# How to mount filesystem at boot when filesystem exist

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I have Linux mint 13 maya installed on USB Pendrive (my portable linux). I run it on different computers. Is there a way to set the fstab to auto mount the hard drive from X computer at boot?

So far i have this fstab

```
proc    /proc   proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0   0
tmpfs                  /tmp          tmpfs     nodev,nosuid          0      0
UUID="3f4f873f-3429-49ec-aa92-c0b32f22b057" none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/sdb1   /   ext4    noatime,relatime,errors=remount-ro  0   1
#/dev/sda2  /media/win7 defaults,nofail,user,noauto 0   0
```

I would like Mint would be able to mount partition /dev/sda2 on my laptop. When the partition doesn't exist at boot the system prompts what to do. I would like the system to ignore the mount when the partition is not present.

Is there some way to archieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on your mount line.

> /dev/sda2  /media/win7 defaults,nofail,user,noauto 0   0

You're missing the filesystem type.  It should read:

> **/dev/sda2  /media/win7 ntfs-3g defaults,nofail,user,noauto 0   0**

Assuming you have the ntfs-3g software installed on your pendrive.

If you haven't got ntfs-3g install it with:

> sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g

You may want to also look through this link from the ubuntu forums on safe read/write for ntfs volumes.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=217009

Mind you, this also assumes that the drive will always be at /dev/sda2 and that the drive is formatted as ntfs.  It may not be.  But at least this should work for your laptop and a some computers.  If I'm not mistaken win7 also has a tiny partition at the beginning of the drive used for the boot loader so the C drive may even be at /dev/sda5.

Comment: Write access to NTFS via Linux is still considered a bad idea. NTFS is closed source and I have known it to corrupt more than one NTFS partition. Beware

Comment: is it possible to use UUID to mount the ntfs partition?